# View an Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am currently learning about APIs in general and I want to make a simple api that can be able to receive and send requests. I created a simple API using ASP.NET Core and the Entity Framework in order to use and save data to a local SQL Server.

[This is the tutorial that I used in order to create the database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db#create-your-database)

However, I am now wondering if there is a way to view the database tables and their contents like in phpMyAdmin. Is it possible?

Comment: What database engine are you using? If it's MSSQL then you could access the schema using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: It is a MSSQL Local DB. I'll look that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can view it by clicking Tools > Connect to Database.
Find your database table and right-click to get the option to view the data.

Personally I use SQL Server Management Studio to connect and view my data.
Find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 for SQL Server Management Studio.  To connect to `localDb` with it, the server name will be `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` and use "Integrated Security" on the connection window.